# Why isn't there a viable mod_ruby for Apache yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

As popular as Ruby and Rails are, it seems like this problem would already be solved. JRuby and mod_rails are all fine and dandy, but why isn't there an Apache mod for just straight Ruby?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The basic problem is this: for a long time, MRI was the only feasible Ruby Implementation. MRI has a number of problems that make it hard to embed it into another application (which is basically what [mod_ruby](http://ModRuby.Net/) does: it embeds MRI in Apache), especially a multi-threaded one (which Apache is). It is not particularly thread-safe and it has quite a bit of global state.

This global state means for example that if one Rails application modifies some class, then *all other* Rails applications that run on the same Apache server, will *also* see this modified class.

Another problem is that the MRI source code is not easily hackable. MRI is now more than 15 years old, and it's starting to show.

As a result of these problems, mod_ruby has never *really* properly worked, and at some point the maintainers simply gave up.

The C based PHP interpreter, on the other hand, was designed from day one to be run as mod_php inside Apache. Indeed, for the first couple of versions, there wasn't even a commandline version of the interpreter, mod_php was the *only* way to run PHP.

[Phusion Passenger (aka mod_rack aka mod_rails)](http://ModRails.Com/) solves this problem by basically giving up and sidestepping the problem: they simply run a seperate copy of MRI in a seperate process for every application. It works great, and not only for Ruby. It supports [WSGI](http://WSGI.Org/) (standard interface for Python Web Frameworks), [Rack](http://Rack.RubyForge.Org/) (standard interface for Ruby Web Frameworks) and direct support for Ruby on Rails.

My hopes are on [mod_rubinius](https://GitHub.Com/rue/mod_rubinius/), which unfortunately doesn't exist yet. [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/) was designed from the beginning to be thread-safe, embeddable, free of global state, not use the C stack and so on. It was designed to be able to run multiple Rubinius VMs inside one Rubinius process. This makes mod_rubinius infinitely easier to implement and maintain than mod_ruby. Unfortunately, of course, Rubinius is not released yet, and the real work on mod_rubinius cannot even begin until Rubinius is released. The good news is that mod_rubinius already has more manpower behind it than mod_ruby ever had, because it has paid developers working on it by a Rails hosting company that *desperately* wants to use it themselves.

Answer (score 23):

There is [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/), a robust Apache module that can run [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) applications with minimum configuration. It's becoming appealing to shared hosts, and turning any program into a Rack application is ridiculously easy:

> A Rack application is an Ruby **object**
>   (not a class) that responds to `call`.
>   It takes exactly *one argument*, the
>   environment and returns an Array of
>   exactly *three values*: The status, the
>   headers, and the body.

Answer (score 5):

It's perhaps worth double-clarifying mislav's point that mod_rails isn't actually limited to Rails code at all. The new name, mod_rack, is way better. Trivially small apps can be rackable -- their example being:

```
class HelloWorld
  def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Hello world!"]]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

There is one:  [mod_ruby](http://www.modruby.net/en/), but it hasn't been maintained in about 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

There is [mod_rails](http://www.modrails.com/) and it can run [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) applications, what more can you need?